# How to add two CSS Class to control in the code behind?

Tags: asp.net, css

I am setting 2 css class in the code behind in ASP.NET

I could either do:

```
txtBox.Attributes.Add("class", "myClass1");
txtBox.Attributes.Add("class", "myClass2");
```

it's always apply one Class .. How can i add thw two classes ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The Add method is actually a Put, since it replaces the value behing the key `"class"`. In HTML/css you can have several classes by separating with a space.

```
txtBox.Attributes.Add("class", "myClass1 myClass2");
```

Comment: Actually it is better to set class directly to CssClass attribute: `txtBox.CssClass = "myClass1 myClass2"`. In this way you can also add/remove classes later: `txtBox.CssClass += " myClass3"` / `txtBox.CssClass.Replace("myClass1", "")`

Comment: This is what I needed, Marc and @Grengas.  I would have done this straight away but was looking for a more normalized interface to the CSS class than twiddling a flat string.  Par for the course, I guess.

Answer (score 8):

try

```
txtBox.Attributes.Add("class", "myClass1 myClass2");
```

I think this will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try

txtBox.CssClass = "myClass1 myClass2";

Comment: Not helpful because this will replace existing classes

Comment: Worked for me since I needed multiple classes during control creation.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
txtBox.Attributes.Add("class", "my_Class1 my_Class2");
```