# I need to change asp:buttons that are in a ListView from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, listview, code-behind

I have some buttons in list view and I need to change their CSS attributes through code behind so the color can be changed dynamically through functions.

I get the following error:

```
**Error 6 The name 'SubDomainButton' does not exist in the current context.**
```

I would be happy being able to edit the CSS Class currently assigned to the buttons or reference the Button that is inside the ListView.

I want to do something like...

```
SubDomainButton.Style.Add("border-color", (string)    (Session["BorderFontColor"]));
SubDomainButton.Style.Add("color", (string)(Session["BorderFontColor"]));
SubDomainButton.Style.Add("background-color", (string)(Session["BackgroundColor"]));
```

HTML Segment:

```
<asp:ListView ID="SubDomainListView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SubDomainSqlDataSource"
                    EnableModelValidation="True" OnItemCommand="SubDomainListView_ItemCommand">

                    <itemtemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="SubDomainButton" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubDomain") %>' CommandText="click" CommandName="Select"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' UseSubmitBehavior="False" CssClass="button" />
                </itemtemplate>
                    <selecteditemtemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubDomain") %>' CommandText="click" CommandName="Select"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' UseSubmitBehavior="False" CssClass="buttoninact" Enabled="False"   />
    </selecteditemtemplate>
                    <layouttemplate>
                    <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                    </div>
                </layouttemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

CSS:
    /* Button Styles */

```
.button {
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.0.1) 0 1px 0 0;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.0.1) 0 1px 0 0;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.0.1) 0 1px 0 0;
border: 1px solid;
font-family: Lucida Grande,Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 700;
padding: 2px 6px;
height: 28px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
text-decoration: underline;
}

/*Hover Styles*/
.button:hover {
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.0.1) 0 1px 0 0;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.0.1) 0 1px 0 0;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.0.1) 0 1px 0 0;
border: 1px solid;
font-family: Lucida Grande,Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 700;
padding: 2px 6px;
height: 28px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.buttoninact {
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.0.1) 0 1px 0 0;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.0.1) 0 1px 0 0;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.0.1) 0 1px 0 0;
border: 1px solid;
font-family: Lucida Grande,Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 700;
padding: 2px 6px;
height: 28px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Look at the post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955951/how-to-add-two-css-class-to-control-in-the-code-behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding inline CSS styles:

```
<itemtemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="SubDomainButton" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubDomain") %>' CommandText="click" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' UseSubmitBehavior="False" CssClass="button"
style='<%# String.Format("border-color: {0}; color: {1}; background-color: {2};",(string)Session["BorderFontColor"],(string)Session["BorderFontColor"],(string)Session["BorderFontColor"]) %>' />
</itemtemplate>
```

Comment: I get the following: Error 6 The name 'SubDomainButton' does not exist in the current context.  I would imagine this is because it's in a listview?

Comment: It's because the id gets prefix whilst page rendering. Set the attribute ClientIDMode to "static" and it should work.

Comment: Sorry that give me the error: Error 6 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Attributes' and no extension method 'Attributes' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about typing the b variable. Try to add (Button) as I did in my edit. Hope it will work.

Comment: that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Try to check my edit. I tested it and it should work for you. But the style only changes on page reload. Is it enough for you?